# Using ParentClass.method(self, *args, **kwargs) or super(MyClass, self).method(*args, **kwargs)

Tags: syntax, python

When one has a class that inherits from a single class, what is the preferred, and most pythonic, way to call parent methods? There are two ways that I know of to call the parent method.

*Option 1:*

```
ParentClass.method(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

*Option 2:*

```
super(MyClass, self).method(*args, **kwargs)
```

Option 1 definitely seems to make a lot of sense when dealing with multiple inheritance; we want to specifically call the method of a certain class. But when dealing with single inheritance, either way works, though Option 1 is probably more future safe. But is there anything (like a PEP) that says when to use which style?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, if you have old-style classes you need to use *Option 1*.

If not, it depends on the code:

- If the superclass (or subclasses) uses `super` (or nothing), you can safely use super. This also means your subclsses *must* use `super` instead of `Parent.method(self, ...)`.
- If the superclass (or subclasses) uses the old `Parent.method(self, ...)`, also use it.

There's a good and much more verbose explanation at http://fuhm.net/super-harmful/.
The short summary (even shorter than my explanation above):

> - Subclasses must use super if their superclasses do
> - Superclasses must use super if their subclasses do (sometimes)